# Email ID's from a SAS Dataset in Body

Tags: email, sas

I'm trying to send out ID's of a SAS dataset in  an email but not able to     get the format right. I just need plain text as html is getting stuck and slow.       Thanks in advance to help! Any one solution would be good.

I have one ID column. The first solution one gives a complete list like

```
%include "/saswrk/go/scripts/envsetup.sas";
filename mymail email "&emaillist."
subject="  &env. Records Transferred on %sysfunc(date(),yymmdd10.)";
data null;
set WORKGO.recds_processed;
file mymail;
put (_all_)(=);
run; quit;
```

Output

```
ID=1
ID=2
ID=3
ID=4
ID=5
```

It would be nice if i could get the count and output like 
Number of records processed=6 and the ID's are 1,2,3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
%include '/saswrk/go/scripts/envsetup.sas';

filename mymail email "&emaillist"
    subject = "&env Records Transferred on %sysfunc(date(), yymmdd10.)";

data _null_;
    length id_list $ 3000;
    retain id_list '';

    set workgo.recds_processed nobs = nobs end = eof;
    file mymail;

    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        put 'Number of records processed=' nobs;
        put 'The IDs are:';
    end;

    /* Print the IDs in chunks */
    if length(strip(id_list)) > 2000 then do;
        put id_list;
        call missing(id_list);
    end;

    call catx(', ', id_list, id);

    if eof then put id_list;
run;
```

At the first iteration of the data step, when `_n_ = 1`, the number of observations in the dataset is written to the file.

Then, at each iteration, the current ID is appended to a comma-separated list of IDs. When the length of the list exceeds 2,000, the contents of the list is printed and the list is reset to empty. This ensures that the maximum length of a SAS character string is never reached, thereby avoiding errors.

When the end of the input dataset is reached, the current contents of the list is output.

This will give you multiple chunks of comma-delimited IDs where each chunk is separated by a newline.

To append the IDs from a second dataset you can simply modify the existing file using the `mod` keyword in the `file` statement and write the observations in an otherwise identical manner.

```sql
data _null_;
    length id_list $ 3000;
    retain id_list '';

    set workgo.recds_not_processed nobs = nobs end = eof;
    file mymail mod;

    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        put 'Number of records not processed=' nobs;
        put 'The IDs are:';
    end;

    /* Print the IDs in chunks */
    if length(strip(id_list)) > 2000 then do;
        put id_list;
        call missing(id_list);
    end;

    call catx(', ', id_list, id);

    if eof then put id_list;
run;
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for the quick reply. It sent out the email but did not send all the ID's and here is the WARNING

ARNING: In a call to the CATX routine, the first argument was not long enough to contain the concatenation of all the arguments. The correct result would contain 1009 characters, but the actual result was truncated to 1000 character(s). The following note indicates the left-most argument that caused truncation.

Comment: Alex,

Sorry, I'm a newbie and i have almost 60000 ID's to return and if i increated the id_list size to 32000 but still get the below warning 

WARNING: In a call to the CATX routine, the first argument was not long enough to contain the concatenation of all the arguments. The correct result would contain 32009 characters, but the actual result was truncated to 32000 character(s). The following note indicates the left-most argument that caused truncation.

Comment: Alex,

Thanks you very very much for working on this. No there are no dups.  I think you know the best how to do it so I will go with whatever you suggest.

Comment: They want the ID's in the body. Is it hard?

Comment: Alex, Thanks a lot again. We can just have the same comma separated. A long list is hard to scroll down so that's the reason we were looking for something like a paragraph thing.

If we have 2 data sets one which got transferred and other which did not get transferred like workgo.recds_NOT_processed and want to report that in the same email , can we do that?

Just like the one we reported I want to report in the same email number of awards not processed and its count.

Comment: Alex, thanks and no worried, you are doing me a favor and I think I'm asking a lot.

The ID's are breaking in between like 123,456,6
43,789,101,8
23

Is there a way to eliminate that. Also, I don't know exactly how to combine both the codes you gave for awards processed and not processed. Sorry :(

Comment: @etl_tool: To combine "processed" and "not processed," simple execute the second data step after the first. So run the code in this post in the order in which I present it, all in one program. As for the IDs breaking in between, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Comment: Alex,sorry for delay. If you see there is a line break between some lines but the point where it's breaking, the ID is splitting into parts. So when I search for 063097 it will not find it as it's split into 063
097
and same case with 0112117 which is split into 011
2117

Number of records processed=65000
The IDs are:
0348271, 0093514, 9120590, 0423882, 1400466, 0700306, 0296171, 0514977, 0925832, 0501251, 0925678, 0407237, 0966524, 0630092, 0630
097,  0301087, 0927572, 0530139, 0840047, 1264855, 0548590, 0933560, 9157190, 0424210, 0134104, 0908895, 0853066, 0324679, 011
2117, AND SO ONN

Comment: In the above comment there is a line break between 063 and 097 
& 011 and 2117 but its showing as space

Comment: Hi Alex,

Getting this error when I combined both the codes.

ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name MOD.

Comment: Alex, I see that if we include CATX in macro it can take upto 65000, i just tried but the email is not goign out.

Comment: Alex, Thank you very much.. I am using the same code, i haven't been able to combine both in one email but we thought separating the ID's processed email and ID's not processed email is better,

Comment: @etl_tool: Sorry I never got back to you! Been very busy. I'm glad you got this working for you.