# SAS Base Dataset as email body output

Tags: email, dependency-injection, sas, radix

I have 2 large SAS Datasets with 65000 ID's. I want to send one email with a ',' as delimiter.

```
SASDATASETNAME.ID_PROCESSED
ID
1
2
3
.
.
65000

SASDATASETNAME.ID_NOT_PROCESSED
ID
a
b

OUTPUT IN ONE EMAIL WITH BODY NEEDS TO BE 
Number of ID's processed=65000
1,2,3,4..
.
.
65000

Number of ID's not processed=2
a,b
```

Comment: Please Improve: What is the actual question? What have you tried?

Comment: This site is not a code-on-request service. If you want assistance, please post your existing SAS code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Isn't this a re-post of your earlier question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488808/email-ids-from-a-sas-dataset-in-body

Comment: Also, why would you want to send 60k IDs as an email body.  It sounds like a terrible solution for solving any problem.  Why not use an attachment.  Or even better - FTP a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
data b;
length one_char $ 1;
do i=1 to 100000;
    one_char=byte(int(25*ranuni(0)+65)); *** return an uppercase character;
    output;
end;
run;

data b;
length one_char $ 1;
do i=1 to 100000;
    one_char=byte(int(25*ranuni(0)+65)); *** give me an uppercase character;
    output;
end;
run;

data c;
length one_char $ 1;
do i=1 to 100000;
    one_char=byte(int(25*ranuni(0)+65)); *** give me an uppercase character;
    output;
end;
run;


/*** assuming that you have an SMTP server available and SAS is configured to use it */
filename mymail email "your.name@somesite.com"
subject="whatever you'd like to put in the subject line";


data _null_; 
length concatenated $ 32676;
retain _linelength 200;
file mymail;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    put 'Hi there!' /;
put;
end;
concatenated = '';
put / 'Dataset B' /;
do while(not blast);
    set b end=blast;
    concatenated = strip(concatenated) || ',' || one_char;
    if length(concatenated) > _linelength or blast then do;
        concatenated = substr(concatenated,2);
        put concatenated;
        concatenated='';
    end;
end;
concatenated = '';
put / 'Dataset C' /;
do while(not clast);
    set c end=clast;
    concatenated = strip(concatenated) || ',' || one_char;
    if length(concatenated) > _linelength or clast then do;
        concatenated = substr(concatenated,2);
        put concatenated;
        concatenated='';
    end;
end;
stop;
run;
```

Comment: User, sorry I'm aware that this is not a code request service but excuse my newbiness to SAS Base. 

Robert , yes that was my questions but it sent 2 separate emails with some some glitch of a line break. It is our need so that we can search for the ID directly in the email instead of opening an attachment. It looks ugly but servers the purpose. 

Jan thanks a lot and I'm going to try your solution.